# Mapping nested collection attribute with MapStruct 1.2.0

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I'm trying to map the following attributes with **MapStruct 1.2.0**, based on the following Classes

```
ClassA {
String id
List <Object1> artefacts
}

DTOClassA{
String id
List <Object2> artefacts
}

Object1 {
String id
String serialNo
}

Object2 {
String id
String serialNo
}
```

Within my interface mapper, how do I map the serialNo from ClassA artefacts list to the serialNo  DTOClassA artefacts list? I have tried the following but I didnt work:

```
@Mapping(target="artefacts.serialNo", source="artefacts.serialNo")
ClassA mapToDto(DTOClassA dto)
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using MapStruct v1.3.0 and having just the following Mapper set up

```
@Mapper
public interface TestSOMapper {
    ClassA mapToDto(DTOClassA dto);
}
```

leads to the following MapperImpl being auto-generated

```
...
protected Object1 object2ToObject1(Object2 object2) {
    if ( object2 == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Object1 object1 = new Object1();

    object1.setId( object2.getId() );
    object1.setSerialNo( object2.getSerialNo() );

    return object1;
}
...
```

This is what you wanted, isn't it? If the names of the properties wouldn't match I'd suggest writing a second Mapper for Object1 > Object2 mapping.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We are currently using MapStruct 1.2.0, would you know a solution for this version?

Comment: Same behaviour with v1.2.0.Final
Do you get any error message or something else to work with?